# Θ notation for the sum of a geometric series

Tags: runtime, series, big-o

I have a question about geometric series. Why is

> 1 + c + c<sup>2</sup> + ... + c<sup>n</sup> = Θ(c<sup>n</sup>)

when c > 1? I understand why it is Θ(n) if c = 1 and it is Θ(1) if c < 1, but I just can't figure out why it is Θ(c<sup>n</sup>) if c>1.

Thanks!

Comment: you might have more luck at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Comment: Runtime calculation is never off topic when it comes to good programming. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sum of the first n terms of the geometric series

> c<sup>0</sup> + c<sup>1</sup> + ... + c<sup>n-1</sup>

is given by the quantitiy

> (c<sup>n</sup> - 1) / (c - 1)

Note that if c > 1, then this quantity is bounded from above by c<sup>n</sup> - 1 and from below by c<sup>n-1</sup> - 1 / c. Therefore, it is O(c<sup>n</sup>) and Ω(c<sup>n</sup>), so it is Θ(c<sup>n</sup>).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Let c > 1 and g(c) = 1 + c + c<sup>2</sup> + ... + c<sup>n</sup>.

The first thing to realize is that for some n we have S(n) = (c<sup>n+1</sup> - 1) / (c - 1) where S(n) is the sum of the series.

So we have that (c<sup>n+1</sup> - c<sup>n</sup>) / (c-1) <= (c<sup>n+1</sup> - 1) / (c - 1) = S(n) since c<sup>n</sup> >= 1.

So (c<sup>n+1</sup> - c<sup>n</sup>) / (c-1) = (c<sup>n</sup>(c-1)) / (c-1) = c<sup>n</sup> <= S(n)

Thus we have that S(n) >= c<sup>n</sup>.

Now that we have found our lower bound, let's look for the upper bound.

Observe that S(n) = (c<sup>n+1</sup> - 1) / (c - 1) <= (c<sup>n+1</sup>) / (c - 1) = ((c<sup>n</sup>) c) / (c -1).

To simply our view of the algebra a bit, let y = c / (c-1) and substitute it into the equation above.

Hence, S(n) <= y * c<sup>n</sup> where **y** is just some constant since **c** is! This is an important observation since now it is just a multiple of  c<sup>n</sup>.

So now we have found our upper bound as well.

Thus we have c<sup>n</sup> <= S(n) <= y * c<sup>n</sup>.

Therefore, S(n) = Θ(c<sup>n</sup>) when c > 1.